# Hide methods inherited from Object from Sandcastle-generated documentation?

Tags: c#, documentation, sandcastle

How can I hide methods that are inherited from the Object class (such as Equals, Finalize, GetHashCode, GetType, etc...) from Sandcastle-generated documentation.  I have a class called LicenseManager that has a single method, and the Object inherited methods are clogging the display.

I am using the latest version of Sandcastle + Sandcastle Help File Builder.

http://cl.ly/3Y2p1C0m1a3f160z0y2v

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found an option in "Sandcastle Help File Builder" that does this.

Set (DocumentInheritedFrameworkMembers = false) in the Visibility option group.